# implementing pdf lighbox using bumpbox,mootools.js and making sure the user scrolls to end of document

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, popup, mootools

I have a data access policy(pdf format at a url) in place which I want to show as a pop-up lightbox for the users. The users should scroll down and then agree to it.

I used the bumpbox-2.0.1-min.js and mootools.js files to implement the PDF lightbox but it is not working for me. The code is as below:

HTML

```
<div class="pure-controls submit_form">
    <input id="cb" type="checkbox" required> I've read the
      <a href="http://wiki.abc.com/abc/Data_protection.pdf" class="bump">Data Access Policy</a>
       </label><br>
    <button type="submit" name="edit_value" class="pure-button">Submit Request</button> 
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/bumpbox-2.0.1-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">doBump('.bump');</script>
```

Can anyone please let me know what am i doing wrong over here? Also, how do I make sure the user scrolls down to the end of the page and then hits submit in the lightbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Mootools compat here (jsfiddle versions 1.3.2 or 1.4.5 works for me). Otherwise you get a error for `Browser.version.name` in the bumpbox .js file.
You can find it [**here**](http://mootools.net/download).

This actually works on Mootools 1.2.6, but not on 1.3 no compat.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uuxHu/)

Comment: Okay I am now using "mootools-1.2.6-core-nc.js" but it does not work either. There is some compatibility issues with the bumpbox and the mootools versions i guess.

Comment: I tried the following code @sergio `<script type="text/javascript"> jquery.noconflict();doBump('.bump');</script>` but it would not give a popup lightbox.

Comment: @rond, don't go to 1.2, use a newer version. Do you get any console error when you use 1.3 or 1.4? If you have a live link you can post it here.

Comment: @sergio- I did try the later version but did not work. I am starting to think this is a problem with the PDF. It may not be viewable in the browser and only downloadable, that is what is causing the problem. How do I implement a workaround for that?

Comment: @sergio-yes it does work. I tried the same in my jsfiddle and it worked for me too for a test pdf...

Comment: @sergio-yup..its more like an intranet link where the pdf exists..my guess is that it is in an ONLY DOWNLOADABLE format...I tried using the embed tag too but it would not work...

Comment: @rond is it not a server-side problem maybe? can be worth to post the question somewhere else then. PHP, ASP or whatever you are using...